# Difference between type constructor and return function of a monad (in Haskell)

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm trying to figure out monads in Haskell but didn't get too far yet.

I found https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Understanding_monads#cite_note-1
and several other tutorials/explanations, but none seems to be explaining the difference between the type constructor and the return function.

As I understood the

- type constructor constructs a monad from a given value of the basic data type. So it's sort of a normal constructor like in Java, which builds from the given parameter a new instance.
- `return` function applies the type constructor on the given value of the basic data type and returns the constructed monad.

So what's the point of having two functions doing basically the same?

**EDIT**
So using the example of a Maybe-monad, the

- `country = Just "China"`: (constructor) creates the monad for the value "China".
- `return "China"`: returns the monad which is corresponding to the value of China, so it's basically the monad containing the `"China"` value.

Generally speaking I understand a monad as a container for values. 
One usage of monads is to combine simple/existing computations to more complex computations.

Comment: I'm afraid it did not really understand what you are trying to ask and the few things I did understand seems wrong to me ... can you probably make this a bit more concrete? Let's talk about the `Maybe`-monad to make this simple - `Maybe` is the type constructor, `return = Just` so can you please rephrase your question using this?

Comment: btw: those will never do the same - you can view the type-constructor as a function but it's a function on the type-level - `return` will wrap a value into the monad

Comment: I don't know if I agree with the duplicate ... it seems to be a different issue with the level of understanding here

Comment: @Carsten if in doubt, reopen.

Comment: A type constructor constructs _types_, not values! It's vaguely similar to the `List` part of `List<String>` in Java: given a type (`String`), it produces a type (`List<String>`). Generics is the closest thing Java has to type constructors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Type constructors are type-level functions which return a type. `Maybe` is a type constructor which takes a single type parameter and returns a type e.g. `Maybe String`, `Maybe Int` etc.

data constructors are used to create values of a particular type. For some type `Maybe a` these constructors are `Just` and `Nothing` i.e.

```
data Maybe a = Just a | Nothing
```

The `return` function constructs a monadic value from a 'plain' value e.g.

```
return 1 :: Maybe Int
return "s" :: [String]
```

So in the definition of the `Monad` class

```
class Monad m where
  return :: a -> m a
```

`m` is a type constructor e.g. (`IO`, `Maybe`, `[]`) which is used to construct types, while `return` is a function which constructs a monadic value of type `m a` from a value of type `a`.

For the monad instance of `Maybe`, `return` constructs a value of `Maybe a` with just i.e.

```
instance Monad Maybe where
  return x = Just x
```

so if you know you are dealing with `Maybe` it doesn't matter which you use. However, `return` has a more general type since it can be used to construct an arbitrary value `m a` for some monad `m`.

Comment: So if you compare country and return "China" from the question, what's the difference? Since Maybe is a monad country should contain a monadic value. But so is the result of return "China".

Comment: @Jonas - `Just` is a constructor, `Maybe` is the type constructor. `Just x` and `return x` are the same thing for `Maybe`, but `return` has a more general type in that it applies to any monad so you can use it generically.

Comment: So the return function simply creates an instance of the basic the monad contains? (Just the abstract way of creating the instances of the basic type?)

Comment: @Jonas - Yes `return` is used to create values of `m a` for some type constructor `m` for which there is a `Monad` instance.

Answer (score 1):

A type constructor constructs a type out of other types. It is not a function and has nothing to do with values.

In Haskell, `[]` is a type constructor. When applied to a type, say `Int`, it makes another type `[Int]`.

Incidentally, in Java `[]` is a type constructor too. It can make a new type `Int[]` out of existing type `Int`.

Perhaps you wanted to ask about data constructors. Indeed, `[]` is also a data constructor (different from the type constructor spelled `[]`) and in certain contexts it is equivalent to `return`. Why do we need `return` then?  `return` works for any monad and can be used to write generic monadic code that works for any monad. It is a *generalization* of `[]` and `Just` and `Left` and...

Comment: `return`/`pure` are just generalizations of value constructors. It is that simple. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

In

```
  (>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

- `m` is a constructor of a type that is instance of the `Monad` class
- `m a` is NOT a constructor application but a pattern matching to extract `m` and `a`
- `a->m b` is a pattern against a function of `m b`. Let's call it `k`.
- `>>=` needs to map to what `k` maps to ('returns'), i.e. apply `k a`

The implementation from `Maybe`

```
    (Just x) >>= k      = k x
```

In a `do`

- `>>=` binds `someMonad <- mConstructorSmartOrNot someParam` to the next line
- `>>` binds `mConstructorSmartOrNot someParam` to the next line

```
    return :: Monad m => a -> m a
```

`return` is basically the same as `m`,
but since `m` can be any
constructor (of a value of a variable of an `m`-constructed type),
we can refer to it generally with this one name.

A monad constructs and forwards context.